# Highlighting / applying style to filter string in element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on the following code. How can I highlight the selected filters in the elements?

I already tried this

```
$(this).html(function(_, html)
{
    return html.replace(new RegExp(filter, 'gi'), '<span style="font-weight:bold">$&</span>');
});
```

but look like I am not doing right way!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#filter").keyup(function(){
        var filter = $(this).val(), count = 0;

        $("nav ul li").each(function(){
            if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
                $(this).fadeOut();

                $(this).html(function(_, html) {
                    return html.replace(new RegExp(filter, 'gi'), '<span style="font-weight:bold">$&</span>');
                });
            } else {
                $(this).show();
                count++;
            }
        });

        var numberItems = count;
        $("#filter-count").text("Number of Comments = "+count);
    });
});
```

```css
body{
  padding:50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="live-search" action="" class="styled" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <input type="text" class="text-input" id="filter" value="" />
        <span id="filter-count"></span>
    </fieldset>
</form>

<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Jim James</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Hello Bye</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Wassup Food</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Bleep bloop</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">jQuery HTML</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CSS HTML AJAX</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">HTML5 Net Set</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Node Easy</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Listing Bloop</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact HTML5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CSS3 Ajax</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ET</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: So you only want to highlight matches and not remove everything *but* the matches?

Comment: Calm down, it happens all the time, please answer my question, I'll try to help. BTW I didn't vote to close, your question is fine IMO.

Comment: Thanks zer00ne, yes need to highlight maching strings

Comment: @MonaCoder: please keep your temper here. I have flagged your remark. It is OK to disagree with a duplicate/off-topic assessment, but most such suggestions are given in good faith. Thus, a respectful and discursive tone is appropriate.

Comment: The close vote you have received is the assessment that your question does not have an [mcve]. If the elements in the filtered list are always a regex match for what is in the input box, what would you want emboldened? I suspect that since this is not clear, the close vote is reasonable. Perhaps you could edit the question to stop it being put on hold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to add a class instead of inline style like:

```
.charBold {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
}
```

Move the regex to the else part of **if** and before apply the regex you need to remove the previous span if any:

```js
$("#filter").keyup(function () {
    var filter = $(this).val(), count = 0;

    $("nav ul li a").each(function () {
        if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
            $(this).parent().fadeOut();
        } else {
            $(this).html(function (_, html) {
                var retVal = $(this).text(); // remove any span...
                return (filter.trim().length == 0) ? retVal :  retVal.replace(new RegExp(filter, 'gi'), '<span class="charBold">' + filter + '</span>');
            });
            $(this).parent().show();
            count++;
        }
    });

    var numberItems = count;
    $("#filter-count").text("Number of Comments = " + count);
});
```

```css
body {
    padding: 50px;
}

.charBold {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="live-search" action="" class="styled" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <input type="text" class="text-input" id="filter" value=""/>
        <span id="filter-count"></span>
    </fieldset>
</form>

<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Jim James</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Hello Bye</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Wassup Food</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Bleep bloop</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">jQuery HTML</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CSS HTML AJAX</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">HTML5 Net Set</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Node Easy</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Listing Bloop</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact HTML5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CSS3 Ajax</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ET</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks gaetanoM this is exactly what I want

Comment: but there is an issue here

Comment: Can you please tary to search with `a` it is going to append the HTML to a string